# How to read data from AG-Grid container without scrolling it in Selenium IDE

Tags: ui-automation, selenium-ide, ag-grid

I am trying to read a data from a column in the AG-Grid container where required column is at the end of the container and needs to scroll down to see it.

When I write below line in Selenium IDE and run

```
WaitForText              <Target>               <value>
```

this turns yellow and keeps on waiting. When I scroll the container at the end then it continue running.

I am new to AG-Grid so Please help me to fetch the data automatically without the need to scroll.

Comment: Exactly, Even I think so. I tried same with katalon studio as well but still same issue. Would really appreciate any help or pointers to automate web pages which uses AG-Grid.

Comment: The reason Ag-grid can be so fast and smooth is because not all of the rows are in the DOM until you scroll to their position.

Comment: Did this get resolved? I need to automate testing of some ag-grids with Selenium Webdriver.Thanks.